# Some trouble with WinAnt --> command "ant" dosnt exist or is wrong written?

Tags: java, ant

I've some trouble with winAnt. Everytime I try to start the "build" process with the command "ant build" on the cmd it returns the Error that the command "ant" dosn't exist or is wrong written.

So what did I do till now?:

1. I am using Windows 7 32 bit-Version
2. Get the Java JDK from oracle website
3. Get WinAnt from http://code.google.com/p/winant/     (v 1.8.2)
4. Installed Java JDK
5. Installed WinAnt and point to the directory C: Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/
6. go to cmd.exe
7. go to directory i want to compress and type:"ant build"

-->Then the error message occures as mentioned abov....

So do anyone know what I am doing wrong all the time?

-Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add ant to your path. [The docs say it better than I can.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#windows)

Comment: mhm, so I tried to do the following in cmd "set ANT_HOME=c:\Program Files\WinAnt\bin\"
but this dosnt work the cmd tells me that the variable "set ANT_HOME=c:\Program Files\WinAnt\bin\" is not defined...

Comment: I tried again with all this setting (i typed in my paths to the directory mentioned in the docs) 
set ANT_HOME=c:\ant
set JAVA_HOME=c:\jdk-1.5.0.05
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin

and tried it again, but still this "ant" dosnt exist error

Comment: if you have spaces in your path you probably have to put quotes around it, setting the same exact path as in the docs won't do you any good, it's the path to your installation you need!

Comment: Hi I do it like this for example: set ANT_HOME="c:\Program Files\WinAnt" and set JAVA_HOME="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01" and set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin but it dosnt work....

Comment: Now I've done it right. So I went to my directorey in cmd with "cd mydirectory/build" and type "ant build" now the the following error is there.

Files\WinAnt""==""" cannot syntactically processed

mhm... I have rly no idea what i can do

Answer (score 0):

The last comment above indicates, you have problems due to `space` in the ant installation.

It would *arguably* be simpler if you used the official ant [binary distribution](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), instead of the [installer](http://code.google.com/p/winant/). I wonder if it has some quirks.

How about giving a shot with the binary installation?